# Write to file in app script project

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google app script project that pulls some data and writes it to a spreadsheet a couple times a month. I'm creating a web app to show some calculations using this data. I have some functions that I call with google.script.run to pull the data and format it as json. That seems to be a little slow and I was thinking that since the data only changes twice a month, I could programatically write it out as json to a project file and then include it with HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('JavaScript') instead of loading it from the spreadsheet every time the page loads.

Is it possible to write to a project file from within your app script code?

Comment: No, you can't use Apps Script to deploy itself.

Comment: Define "a little slow", and "some data". Reading values is proportional to the number of values to be read, but this value can be easily dwarfed by poorly implemented server-side methods. That's a separate question than you've asked, so consider posting to Code Review.

Comment: I read in 2 sheets. One is 4x22 cells and the other is 6x6. The first sheet will grow beyond 22 rows. "A little slow" is a few seconds, but it's every time the page is loaded. I figured since this data is only updated every 15 days or so, it doesn't make sense to make calls like this when it could be written out to something that's less expensive to read.

Comment: Those reads should take about 0.1s or less - reading 5000 R x 40 C takes about 35 seconds. You should develop a post for Code Review, or if that is not a good fit, ask a pertinent question here.